# Use found Data from Windows ID and put it into an email through Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that gets the specific part of a text file, read it and then put it into the contents of an email and sends it. This is what I currently have:

```
$logs = (Get-EventLog system | where {$_.InstanceId -eq 7001 -and 
$_.TimeWritten -gt (Get-Date).Adddays(-1)}).TimeWritten | Out-String
#to file
$logs | Out-File ".\Results.txt"

#create COM object named Outlook 
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application 
#create Outlook MailItem named Mail using CreateItem() method 
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
#add properties as desired 
$Mail.To = "SomeMailAddress.com" 
$Mail.Subject = "Time" 
$Mail.Body = $logs
#send message 
$Mail.Send() 
#quit and cleanup 
$Outlook.Quit() 
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook) | Out-Null
```

I'm able to create the text file, output the data, I believe the Get-Content is getting that specific portion of time but I'm not sure how to use Set-Content and put that into the email. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to send email through PowerShell is by using `Send-MailMessge`.

Below is how you would send using the Outlook ComOjbect.
Note: If you have to use the outlook comobject, make sure you run PowerShell and outlook the same way with the same account.

Example:

```
$logs = (Get-EventLog system | where {$_.InstanceId -eq 7001 -and $_.TimeWritten -gt (Get-Date).Adddays(-1)}).TimeWritten  | Out-String 

#create COM object named Outlook 
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application 
#create Outlook MailItem named Mail using CreateItem() method 
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
#add properties as desired
$Mail.To = "jrider@yourDomain.com" 
$Mail.Subject = "Time" 
$Mail.Body = $logs
#send message 
$Mail.Send() 
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook) | Out-Null
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a specific portion of the text (the time) which is the only thing i need, is there an easier way to get just the one portion? I was thinking: Export to text -> Read the text -> Get that specific portion -> put into email. If there's a way to do: Get time from log -> Put into email, that would be even better!

Comment: @MitchellMonarch . I have updated the solution to only get the timegenerated in the `$logs` variable

Comment: This doesn't appear right and when attempting to run, does not incorporate the time into the body section. You have an Out-String but no other parameter as a heads up. Is it Out-String Time or something along those lines? Time is accurate, just getting it into the body is what I'm having issues with :'D

Comment: @MitchellMonarch Sorry, I did not test my last update. I just tested it with an updated solution and it works. To answer your question `out-string` just puts the output in a string format

Comment: @MitchellMonarch `Out-String` should be on it's own. You should be able to run `$logs = (Get-EventLog system | Where-Object {$_.TimeWritten -gt (Get-Date).Adddays(-1)}).TimeWritten | Out-String `
Then call `$logs` as a test. This is what your mail body will have

Comment: I've updated my code, the body is completely blank, I'm using the outlook communication object as the send-mail doesn't work on my end. Sorry for the inconvenience and ty for your help this far, I appreciate it. Just need to somehow get $logs into the body...

Comment: @MitchellMonarch I have updated the solution to use the Outlook ComObject. Note. If you have to use this route, make sure that you are running outlook and powershell as the same user in the same way (both as admin / normal).